# Setting attributedText, NSRangeException error

Tags: ios, uitextview, nsattributedstring, nsrange, nsrangeexception

Trying to set my UIText view's attributed text properties via selection. Almost works. Action to set text with red font color below. This works sometimes, but often gives an error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason:
>   'NSMutableRLEArray objectAtIndex:effectiveRange:: Out of bounds'

This happens even while there seems to be many more characters in the text view than indicated by the selected range.

```
- (IBAction)setText:(id)sender {

    NSMutableAttributedString * string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithAttributedString:myTextView.attributedText];
    [string addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor redColor] range:NSMakeRange(p1,p2)];

    myTextView.attributedText = string;

}
```

p1 and p2 are the start and end of the selected text. They are generated with the code below, which seems to work as expected:

```
- (void)textViewDidChangeSelection:(UITextView *)textView {

    UITextRange *selectedRange = [myTextView selectedTextRange];

    p1 = [myTextView offsetFromPosition:myTextView.beginningOfDocument toPosition:[selectedRange start]];
    p2 = [myTextView offsetFromPosition:myTextView.beginningOfDocument toPosition:[selectedRange end]];

 }
```

**EDIT: I fixed the problem after reading @borrrden's comment.** Instead of `NSMakeRange(p1,p2)]` I am using `NSMakeRange(p1,p2-p1)]`.

Comment: I could not reproduce the error. Can you narrow down the situations it is occuring?

Comment: Why are you using `selectedTextRange`?  It seems that `selectedRange` would be much easier

Comment: Regardless, `NSMakeRange` takes parameters of start and **length** not start and end.

Comment: @borrrden Thanks I bet that is it. I'll comment again tomorrow if that fixes it.

Comment: @borrrden That was it, works now. Thanks! Add the answer and I can accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to be careful about `NSMakeRange`.  I've answered another question with the same answer before, but it takes a start value and a **length** value, not a start value and an end value as you are trying to use it.